# spring boot app: swagger page on tomcat loads, but shows no APIs

Tags: spring-boot, swagger

I have a spring boot app (2.7.11) with swagger enabled.
When I launch it standalone, with embedded web server, the swagger page loads fine at this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html
```

But when I deploy it in an existing instance of Tomcat it doesn't, meaning that the page load at this URL:

```
http://localhost/JwtConsole/swagger-ui/index.html
```

but it shows no APIs, and there is this message:
No operations defined in spec!

This is my configuration class:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableWebMvc
public class SwaggerConfig
{

    @Bean
    public Docket api()
    {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/services.*"))
                .build()
                .apiInfo(this.apiInfo())
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer webMvcConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addRedirectViewController( "/swagger-ui", "/swagger-ui/index.html");
            }
        };
    }
    
    private ApiInfo apiInfo()
    {
        ApiInfoBuilder apiInfoBuilder = new ApiInfoBuilder();
        apiInfoBuilder.title("REST API");
        apiInfoBuilder.description("REST API Generation");
        apiInfoBuilder.version("1.0.0");
        apiInfoBuilder.license("GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE, Version 3");
        apiInfoBuilder.licenseUrl("https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html");
        return apiInfoBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

Any idea?
Thanks.